# Optimising Expect in Bash script

Tags: bash, macos, expect

I read a lot of topics on Stack Overflow but didn't succeed to optimise my Bash script with Expect yet.

First some context. I need to run an interactive command on macOS. It's the command to escrow the Bootstrap Token to the MDM sever. This is needed because this is not done automatically in our workflow.

I created the following script for this. Pretty basic; it grabs the username and password in Base64, decodes them, and runs the command.

```
# Get Jamf Pro Parameters
base64username=$4
base64password=$5

# Decode Base64 Parameters
username="$(echo "$base64username" | base64 -d)"
password="$(echo "$base64password" | base64 -d)"

# Escrow Bootstrap Token
expect -c "spawn profiles install -type bootstraptoken
expect \"Enter the admin user name:\"
send \"$username\r\"
expect \"Enter the password for user '$username':\"
send \"$password\r\"
expect \"profiles: Bootstrap Token escrowed\""
```

In general it works well, but it turns out to be unreliable. After a lot of trial and error, I'm pretty sure it's because the default timeout for Expect in Bash of 10 seconds. Sometimes it takes more time to run the command.

So I would like to set a timeout of 60 seconds, but don't know how to do that properly. And if possible, I would like to use an exit code if the command doesn't return a successful escrow.

Would somebody like to assist me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Embedding Expect code in shell scripts is kind of tricky and error-prone. You can try my [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/).

Answer (score 1):

You set the expect `timeout` variable to the special value `-1`. The default timeout is 10 seconds. -1 means "infinite".

Also, you can pass the shell values to expect via the environment, which makes the quoting a lot easier:

```bash
export username password

expect -c '
    spawn profiles install -type bootstraptoken
    expect "Enter the admin user name:"
    send "$env(username)\r"
    expect "Enter the password for user "
    send "$env(password)\r"

    set timeout -1
    expect "profiles: Bootstrap Token escrowed"
'
```

> I would like to exit 0 if the command returns ‘profiles: Bootstrap Token escrowed’, and exit 1 if everything else.

One of the really cool features is that you can expect several things simultaneously and perform actions when that pattern is encountered. `eof` occurs when the spawned process exits.

```
expect {
    "profiles: Bootstrap Token escrowed" {exit 0}
    eof {exit 1}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Trying to understand correct. Should or could I use the export function to make it work properly? Or is this additional? For now, most important is to prevent timing out.

Comment: Already tested it. Looks like adding ‘set timeout -1’ prior to the last line makes all difference for a reliable run. Thanks a lot again!

I hope you or somebody else would like to make it even better. I would like to exit 0 if the command returns ‘profiles: Bootstrap Token escrowed’, and exit 1 if everything else.